# Codificação de texto para RTF em java

Tags: java, codificação-de-caracteres, rtf

Estou tentando modificar um arquivo `.RTF`, onde os parâmetros que serão modificados estão *settados* como números. Porém, seus caracteres estão em **ANSI** creio eu, pois o arquivo tem seu cabeçalho as seguintes diretivas em `RTF`

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252
```

Como eu quero escreve no arquivo e as palavras contém acentos, como posso codificar minha string de modo que ela retorne algo lido pelo `RTF` ???.
Abaixo contém um exemplo da codificação usada no arquivo

```
Usu\'e1rio
Pe\'e7a 
(N\'famero)
```

Answer (score 1):

ANSI é uma normalização, na verdade o código 1252 é associado ao charset Windows-1252. Você pode associar um charset ao seu BufferedReader desta forma:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("caminho para o arquivo"), "Windows-1252"));
```

Testei com um arquivo com encoding 1252 e a acentuação apareceu corretamente. Abaixo o código do teste realizado:

Arquivo (Codificado em Windows-1252):

```
Usu�rio 
N�mero
```

Código:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("src/teste.txt"), "Windows-1252"));

        String linha;
        while((linha = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(linha);
        }

        br.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Resultado:

```
Usuário
Número
```

Comment: Você poderia me falar como você fez o teste ? eu tentei utilizar essa função e infelizmente não deu certo. Eu tentei utilizar em arquivos `.txt` e `.rtf`.